# validate textbox to be number only

Tags: asp.net

Another question please

how to validate textbox to be number only by using custom validation, I mean what is the code??

many thanks

Comment: How to ask question on stackoverflow - http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Details are important... WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET,...? What language? What do you mean by "custom validation"? Do you have an existing validation infrastructure implemented that you want to extend? Are you seeking a solution involving regular expressions, or hoping to find another approach?

Comment: I'm guessing from the wording that this question is about the `CustomValidator` in ASP.Net so this question might have the answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427629/asp-net-validation-to-make-sure-textbox-has-integer-values

Answer (score 2):

try to use following  regExp "^\d+$"

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `HTML Textbox` and validate through `javascript`

```
<input type="text" name="myText" onKeypress="if (event.keyCode < 45 || event.keyCode > 57) event.returnValue = false;">
```

Comment: paste the code in source file

Answer (score 0):

You can 
use a mask or
use the function IsNumeric()

Answer (score 0):

use RegularExpressionValidatorcontrol
 This is a good control to check  phone numbers validation.

Try this

Age:

Read this document.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx

Comment: still is not working by the compare validator beacuse I dim the text box as decimel and when I choose Integer type in the compare validator it gives erorr.  Therefore I need the code in custom validation please, help

Comment: it is not about phone numbers the text box would be used to enter traveling distance so it could be integer or decimel