# My Error is Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net

Markup:

```asp
<asp:TextBox ID="txtScore" runat="server" CssClass="text_50" MaxLength="200" Text=""></asp:TextBox>

<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="maskedSeq" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtScore" Mask="999"
    MessageValidatorTip="true"
    OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus"
    OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError"
    MaskType="Number"
    InputDirection="RightToLeft"
    AcceptNegative="None" 
    ErrorTooltipEnabled="True"
    PromptCharacter=""
    AutoComplete="False" />
```

Codebehind:

```
double score = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)gridEstateScoreItem.FooterRow.FindControl("txtScore")).Text); //error start here
```

The error is:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Why are you converting to an Int32 and storing as a double?

Comment: because in mysql i put score as decimal. so do u have any idea to help me? im newbie in c#.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the debugger to determine what value is in the `Text` property of the `TextBox`. It will be easier to debug if you pull the logic apart into multiple lines, like this:

```
TextBox theTextBox = gridEstateScoreItem.FooterRow.FindControl("txtScore") as TextBox;

if(theTextBox != null)
{
    double score = Convert.ToInt32(theTextBox.Text);
}
```

Put a break point on the line `if(theTextBox != null)` and see what value in `.Text` you have. If it is a string value with letters, then the cast to `Int32` will fail and you need to figure out what is polluting your user input (hint: restrict user input of this text box to just numbers).

Answer (score 0):

your variable score is cast as double, so you should be converting to double.

Its either that, or the text in the textbox is not compatible with integer (its a double or text or something other than a whole number)

edit - I was wrong - an integer will be implicitly converted to a double as mentioned below.

You simply need to validate your text field. Here is an example of validating the text entered.
[asp.net validation to make sure textbox has integer values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427629/asp-net-validation-to-make-sure-textbox-has-integer-values)

Still, I don't see any reason to cast your variable as one type and then convert the value to a different type. It might work, but there would be more over head and it doesn't appear to serve any purpose.

Comment: the Int32 will be implicitly converted to a double.  It's not going to cause that error.  You're probably on to something with the format of the text in the textbox

Comment: @ethan Pethon, is it? this error will happen if i leave score part to blank. if i fill the score part it, there will be no error.

Comment: @harrison, thanks. this error only happen if i leave it blank when i try to save it

Comment: @MissMargrateJeba If your textbox is blank then you will get an error as it is not in the correct format to convert to a number.  You will need to do some validation of the text prior to converting it.

Comment: @harrison, ok, so how to do some validation? im really new in this C#.

Comment: There are validators that will do this for you. this post goes over exactly how to do that.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427629/asp-net-validation-to-make-sure-textbox-has-integer-values