# how to put validation for textbox with asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, validation

I have a Textbox on my webform, for instance 2012 entered in single text box the following text box must enter 2014 or else should give error.Iam trying to validate it by using compare validation but am unable to meet the exact condition what i want.Can i know how can it be done?thnks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net validation to make sure textbox has integer values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427629/asp-net-validation-to-make-sure-textbox-has-integer-values)

Comment: Please format your question properly, otherwise it's not possible to differentiate the text of your question of the user-input. You want to validate that the text in txt2 is equal to the text in txt1?

Comment: For instance if i have entered a value in textbox1 as 2012 then in textbox2 the user must enter 2013 or else must give error

Answer (score 0):

I cant fine wha'ts the hard part here...

```
int number=Convert.ToInt32( textBox1.Text);
 if(number==2014)
 Response.Write("good");
 else
 Response.Write("Bad number");
```

More easy then that?

Answer (score 0):

If your validator should ensure that the text in two `TextBoxes` is equal use a `CompareValidator` with appropriate `ControlToValidate` and `ControlToCompare`:

```
<asp:TextBox id="Txt1" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox id="Txt2" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="Txt2"
    ControlToCompare="Txt1"
    ErrorMessage="Text in second textbox must be equal to text in first textbox!">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

If you also want to ensure that only integers can be inserted, use `DataTypeCheck` and `Integer`:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="Txt2"
    Type="Integer" Operator="DataTypeCheck"
    ErrorMessage="Text in second textbox must be an integer!">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```