# Integer only validation for dynamically added Textbox inside Asp.net Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Below is how my GridView code , since the datatable is a pivoted value so the number of columns cannot be predicted. So I am adding textbox dynamically through code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvData"
                EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display."
                runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2"  
                HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" OnRowDataBound="gvData_RowDataBound"  >
                <RowStyle BorderColor="LightBlue" />
</asp:GridView>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     foreach (var item in columnNames)
                {

                    TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();
                    tfield.HeaderText = item;
                    gvData.Columns.Add(tfield);
                }

                gvData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                gvData.DataBind();}

protected void gvData_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int i = 3; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
            {
                TextboxCount++;
                TextBox txtName = new TextBox();
                txtName.ID = "txt" + Convert.ToString(TextboxCount);
                txtName.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                txtName.Text = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row[columnNames[i]].ToString();
                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(txtName); }}}
```

Now when user try to change value in the textbox I have to validate that they only enter integer value.
Here I am not sure what has to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use int.TyrParse method

Example

```
int number;
string s = "AA";
bool IsInteger = int.TryParse(s, out number);
```

Comment: i thought you had problems with validation logic, been a while since I have used a grid view, try gvData_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)

Comment: here's a similar question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427629/asp-net-validation-to-make-sure-textbox-has-integer-values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427629/asp-net-validation-to-make-sure-textbox-has-integer-values)

Comment: gvData_RowEditing is not firing as the cell already has textbox so i dont provide edit link. Also the link you recommended used asp:RangeValidator in HTML markup but I am generating textbox through code. I tried to fire Text changed event and implement Validator but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript function and that to textbox from code behind like:

```
// Add this gvData_RowDataBound , allownumbers is a javascript function   
txtName.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "javascript:return allownumbers(event);");
```

Or else if you are using .NET 4.5 version then try out this:

```
txtName.Attributes["type"] = "number";
```