# disable hindi characters as input for input type number

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've a textbox of type number. I've disabled text input via javascript. But the text box is accepting hindi strings and numbers. When the user gives hindi number as input, it is converted to english in code behind page. But the hindi characters are creating problem, I should prevent hindi input characters.

```
<input type="number" id="txtWard" onkeypress="return numberOnly(event)" required="required" runat="server" min="0" max="8" />
```

javascript code

```
function numberOnly(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : window.event.keyCode;

    if (charCode <= 13) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        var re = /[0-9]/
        return re.test(keyChar);
    }
}
```

Example of hindi text "हिन्दी" and numbers "१ २ ३ ४". The textbox should not accept hindi text.
How could I disable hindi strings also?

Comment: do you want to allow only numbers??

Comment: yes only numbers. Thank You!

Comment: Give us an example of hindi strings and numbers, for me it work good

Comment: @Pedram example added. Thank You!!!

Comment: @user4221591 I tried to paste your strings but it not accept those characters, it only accept numbers. I don't feel anything wrong with your code.

Comment: @Pedram exactly copy paste is disabled. But if I type hindi characters, it is accepted. Try using google input tools for hindi text. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem has to do with specific characters. Your problem is that the validation is only ran if a character is entered manually, and not if it is e.g. pasted from the clipboard. If you use ASP.NET, you can use built-in validation in addition to your current JS validation, an example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1427777/5098386

edit: or if you want to keep it on the JS, just use `onchange` event instead of `onkeypress`.

Comment: I've asp.net validation but I am trying to implement JS validation also. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

So, I used Google input tools for testing with Hindi characters, and for me work good, if you want to allow only number, you can use `/\D/` to allow only digit, by this you don't need to detect key number, try below code:

```js
function numberOnly(e) {
  if (/\D/g.test(e.value)) {
    e.value = e.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="txtWard" onkeypress="return numberOnly(this)" required="required" runat="server" min="0" max="8" />
```